# How do I get javaws to run in foreground?

Tags: jnlp

I've got a problem with log4j in a JNLP downloaded application that is not putting the log-file output where I think it should be going. I've copied the call string from the properties display of the desktop link, pasted it into a command window and added `-J-Dlog4j.debug=true`.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaws.exe -localfile -J-Dlog4j.debug=true  "C:\JNLP_cache\6.0\48\15d6fd70-33c24d30"
```

But javaws.exe seems to put itself immediately into the background so now I can't find the log4j output either :( (This is on Windows XP BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the Java Console to pop open for JWS applications, and write the details to `System.out`.

Comment: Configuring the Java Console to open was sufficent. Thanks